# How to concat string and variable with wild card in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, centos, sh

I am using Amazon Centos server, I want to check if file exists or not using shell script.

I have a directory location and file name format.

my code:

```
yesterdaydate= date -d '-1 day' '+%Y%m%d'
echo $yesterdaydate
Filetemp='/data/ftp/vendor/processed/ccs_'
Filetemp=$Filetemp$yesterdaydate
echo $Filetemp
```

Expected final result should be like this `/data/ftp/vendor/processed/ccs_20210221_171503_itemsku.xml`

Current result: `/data/ftp/corecentric/processed/ccs_`

I want result in format like `Filetemp_yesterdaydate_wildcard(*)_itemsku.xml`

Wildcard(*) is use as time varies of file creation.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globs (= wildcards) work perfectly fine with variables as long as you don't quote the wildcard.
Here we use arrays and bash's `nullglob` option to count the number of files found.

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
yesterday=$(date -d '-1 day' '+%Y%m%d')
files=(/data/ftp/vendor/processed/ccs_"$yesterday"_*_itemsku.xml)
if (( "${#files[@]}" > 0 )); then
   echo "Found the following ${#files[@]} file(s)"
   printf %s\\n "${files[@]}"
else
   echo "Found nothing"
fi
```

Note that this would also match `...20210222_something that is not a time string_itemsku.xml` if there was such a file. If that's the case you can change the glob `*` to `[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]`.